# MongoDB nested arrays aggregated update array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to create a website that on a user click the like button he toggle the like, so if he liked the post the like is removed and if the post doesn't have the like user will like it.

Data structure of database is like this:

```
{
  "_id":"5f9d838caf0d921703818c89",
  "page": "nickname",
  "posts":[
    {
      "post": postData,
      "likes": ["user1","user3"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a nodejs function to add or remove user name from likes.
Example:

1. user2 click the like button
2. the function to give or remove likes know the post index in "posts" so for example index post 0
3. function check if posts.0.likes contains the like of "user2"
4. if "user2" is not included in array then include it else remove from array

Comment: Use [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array)

Comment: What are the mongoose schemas? And what functions have you tried for the add/remove so far?